# PHP formatting Array to A New Array

Tags: php, arrays, foreach, mapping

Hi guys I am a beginner with PHP and want the best way in terms of performance to convert this array:

```
$old = array(
    20 =>
        array(
            'name' => 'Heels',
            'path' => '1/2/10/15/20',
        ),
    15 =>
        array(
            'name' => 'Sandals',
            'path' => '1/2/80/96/15',
        ),
    10 =>
        array(
            'name' => 'Trainers',
            'path' => '1/2/80/96/10',
        ),
);
```

To this:

```
$new = array(
    20 =>
        array(
            'value' => 20,
            'label' => 'Trainers > Sandals > Heels',
        ),
);
```

There is going to be loads of records surely exploding the paths and mapping them with the ids is going to slow it down in terms of performance just wondering whether there is a more efficient way if possible thanks.

Comment: I am lost where value 20 derives from if the `path` (from which you're explaining creates relatives) are different? Please provide a minimal, complete or verifiable example of an input and output.

Comment: 20 is the end number for each path but it is also the key so the end result needs to the each of the keys name value 1 and 2 from each path are excluded if that makes sense.

Comment: @NewHorizon This doesn't make sense. Can you clarify your logic here? You say "20 is the end number for each path" but `'1/2/80/96/15'` doesn't have 20 anywhere in it.

Comment: Those are just fake numbers for dummy data but everything will have the last three numbers matching.

Comment: Post correct data when you ask a question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another option could be to first create a mapper of the keys and the names. Then you could take the key from the mapper to create the path:

```
$result = [];
$mapper = array_combine(array_keys($old), array_column($old, 'name'));
foreach ($old as $key => $value) {
    $path = implode(' > ', array_map(function($x) use ($mapper) {
        return $mapper[(int)$x];
    }, explode('/', $value['path'])));

    $result[$key] = ['value' => $key,'label' => $path];
}

print_r($result);
```

[Php demo](https://3v4l.org/VL42l)

Comment: Good idea for performance, also great use of `array_column()` rather than looping creating a whole new variable for the names for use of `implode()`. Hope you didn't mind me stealing that to update my question ;) Good answer.

Comment: This answer is the most dynamic solution, I don't see why it doesn't have more votes. I admire the concept of not only matching the OP input to output, but allowing for more inputs to be placed that still query how OP output is intended. Honestly, great solution and made me look into "mappers".

Answer (score 3):

If I understand correctly, you're trying to get the latest path relevant to each category and output it as a breadcrumb.

You can first sort the keys (ids) and then loop through the array creating the breadcrumb.

```
arsort($paths); # This gives the desired output in OP but makes more sense to use krsort() to sort DESC not ASC

$breadcrumb = (object) array (
    'value' => array_keys($paths)[count($paths) - 1], # Get the highest id - if using krsort() use array_keys($paths)[0]
    'labels' => implode(' > ', array_column($paths, 'name'));
);

# Update derived from The fourth bird's answer which skips the need for the foreach().
# Concept is to build an array of the labels to then make look pretty with the > effect
```

Here is a [demo](https://3v4l.org/1lndS).

> Output:
>
> ```
> object (stdClass) (2) {
>     ["value"] => int(20)
>     ["labels"] => string(26) "Trainers > Sandals > Heels"
> }
> ```

Answer (score 0):

This is the hardcoded way, but i think you need to give a bit more information to get a dynamic solution.

```
<?php

$old = array(
    20 =>
        array(
            'name' => 'Heels',
            'path' => '1/2/10/15/20',
        ),
    15 =>
        array(
            'name' => 'Sandals',
            'path' => '1/2/80/96/15',
        ),
    10 =>
        array(
            'name' => 'Trainers',
            'path' => '1/2/80/96/10',
        ),
);


ksort($old);
$breadcrumbs = [];
$currentKey = 0;

foreach ( $old as $itemKey => $item) {
    $currentKey = $itemKey;
    $breadcrumbs[] = $item;

}
$new = [$currentKey] = [
    'value' => $currentKey,
    'label' => implode(' > ', $breadcrumbs)
];

printf($new);
```